# use xx.contain(xxx) in struts2 tag

Tags: tags, struts2, enumeration

Hi:
This is the related eneities in my app:

```
   @Entity
    @Table(
            name = "t_user")
public class User {
    private int                 id;
    private List<RoleType>      role;

    @ElementCollection(
            targetClass = RoleType.class)
    @CollectionTable(
            name = "t_user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "user_id"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    public List<RoleType> getRole() {
        return role;
    }
    //seter and getter
}


public enum RoleType {
    VIP, SysManger, Publisher;
}
```

Now,in my page I want to build the page according to current user's roletype.

So I need something like :

```
<s:set value="#session.current_user" var="cuser"/>
<s:if test="#cuser.role.contains(com.test.entity.RoleType.Publisher)">
    <li><a href="common/listTask_userPub?uid=<s:property value='#cuser.id'/>">Tasks published by Me</a></li>
</s:if>
```

But it does not work at all,so I want to know if there is any other idea to meet my requriement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By this line

```
<s:set value="#session.current_user" var="cuser"/>
```

you are setting the `cuser` scope to action level and in the nest line you are trying to access it from the session level. i guess you need to do something like

```
<s:if test="%{(cuser.role).contains(com.test.entity.RoleType.Publisher)}">
```

thats my high level guess hope it might help you.